# Difference between Delegate1 =new Delegate1(fun) and Delegate1=fun;

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a small doubt, while initializing delegates we usually use `=`. What is the difference between the cases below. Both Work same.

```
public delegate void sam(int i); 

//variant 1    
s = new sam(fun);

//variant 2
s = fun;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between both of them. Both generate the same IL code but the second variant needs C# 2.0 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
sam s = new sam((i) => { });

s = (i) => { };
```

Both of them is same.